# How can I remove the subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello I have the following function that I get from scikit-learn site, I try to reduce the function only for one plot, but I cannot do more than this:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
def plot_learning_curve(estimator,X, y, axes=None, cv=None,
                        n_jobs=None, train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 5)):
    
    _, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10, 20))

    axes[0].set_title('Curvas de error de aprendizaje')
    axes[0].set_xlabel("Nº Ejemplos de entrenamiento")
    axes[0].set_ylabel("Error: 1 - F1")

    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores, fit_times, _ = \
        learning_curve(estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs,
                       train_sizes=train_sizes,
                       return_times=True)
    train_scores_mean = np.mean([1] - train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std([1] - train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean([1] - test_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_std = np.std([1] - test_scores, axis=1)
   

    # Plot learning curve
    axes[0].grid()
    axes[0].fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                         train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                         color="r")
    axes[0].fill_between(train_sizes, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                         test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                         color="g")
    axes[0].plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
                 label="Error de entrenamiento")
    axes[0].plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
                 label="Error de validación medio (cv=10)")
    axes[0].legend(loc="best")

    return plt
```

The question is how can I remove the second subplot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, you're creating the second subplot with the function `plt.subplots()`, where you specify that you want two subplots in the vertical axis with its first argument. To get rid of it, you should write instead:

```
_, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 20))
```

Answer (score 1):

While the answer of The Half-Blood Prince is correct and most cases the suitable choice I want to point out that you can remove the second subplot using

`axes[1].remove()`

This can be useful in some cases, e.g., after creating a 2 by 2 grid of subplots when only 3 are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above correct answers,

you can only use "**plt**" instead of creating subplots. (because you will work only one plot.) And then end of the line just add "**plt.figure()**

Following below;

```
_, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10, 20))

plt.title('Curvas de error de aprendizaje')
plt.xlabel("Nº Ejemplos de entrenamiento")
plt.ylabel("Error: 1 - F1")

train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores, fit_times, _ = \
    learning_curve(estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs,
                   train_sizes=train_sizes,
                   return_times=True)
train_scores_mean = np.mean([1] - train_scores, axis=1)
train_scores_std = np.std([1] - train_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_mean = np.mean([1] - test_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_std = np.std([1] - test_scores, axis=1)
   

# Plot learning curve
plt.grid()
plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                     train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                     color="r")
plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                     test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                     color="g")
plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
             label="Error de entrenamiento")
plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
             label="Error de validación medio (cv=10)")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.figure()
return plt
```